# Show input when a checkbox = checked by default

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, default, show

I have found a way to show/unhide a div when a checkbox is checked, but not when the checkbox is checked by default.

```
<?php 
  $checked=product_exists($row[ 'serial']) ? ' checked="checked"': ''; 
  echo '<input type="checkbox" '. $checked . '> '. $row[ 'name'] .'<br />'; 
?>
```

That's the code that checks the boxes, now I need something to:
-check if a checkbox is checked
-> show its hidden div

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Extra code:

```
<?php $result=mysql_query( "select * from products"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<div class="column">
    <?php $checked=product_exists($row[ 'serial']) ? ' checked="checked"':
    ''; $serial=$row[ 'serial']; echo '<input type="checkbox" '. $checked .
    '> '. $row[ 'name'] . ''. $serial . '<br />'; $result2=mysql_query(
    "select * from productsmenus where serial = $serial"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ echo '<div style="'.($checked===''
    ? 'display: none;' : ''). '"></div>';}?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: just call the same function that hides/shows the div in the onload event of the page. I assume this function checks the state of the checkbox, and hides/shows the div appropriately.

Comment: or you could add a class to the hidden div depending on the value of `$checked`. i.e. `if (strlen($checked)) { echo "show" } else { echo "hide" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps this could be a temp-fix:

```
echo '<div style="'.str_replace('checked="checked"', 'display: none;', $checked).'">';
```

If I'm not mistaken, this is your question, isn't it? hide a div if the checkbox is checked. The other way around is fairly easy, too:

```
echo '<div style="'.($checked === '' ? 'display: none;' : '').'">';
```

But to be brutally honest, I don't think you're going at this the right way. True, I don't know what it is you're trying to do exactly, but still. You're *"building"* your page, but you're still having to check if a given product exists? 
Perhaps look into a way to get all data, so you can pass an array of products to some sort of template script, as is customary in most of today's frameworks.

*Update:*
After looking at your site, you might be better of using JS and AJAX calls:

```
document.body.addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
     var div, checkboxTxt, xhr
     target = e.target || e.srcElement;
     if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' || target.type !== 'checkbox')
     {//value of a non-checkbox changed, ignore event
         return e;
     }
     checkboxTxt = target.parentNode.innerText.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, '').trim();
     if (target.checked === false)
     {//checkbox was unchecked --> hide div
         div = document.getElementBy(checkboxTxt);
         div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
         return e;
     }
     //add div: checkbox was checked
     xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('post', 'your/ajax/url', true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');|
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
     {//things to do with server data
         if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
         {//call complete
             div = document.getElementById(checkboxTxt);//assuming it's hidden... you can create a new element here, too if you like
             div.style.display = 'block';
             div.innerHTML = this.responseText;//or, if it's a JSON object, parse and get the things you need to build the html...
         }
     };
     xhr.send(JSON.stringify({checkbox:checkboxTxt});
}, false);
```

This snippet isn't going to cut it, of course, but it should be enough to get you on track. Happy coding (veel plezier, en succes)

Comment: I want to show the div when the checkbox is checked.
So when a checkbox is checked, they can fill in additional information.
I see you are from belgium so I guess you can read the text, this is the website http://colinch.com/52/contact.php

People can select items from: partycatering and when a product from there is selected it will appear as a checked checkbox on the contact page. And when one is checked, it should display additional information they can fill in. Like for Drinks 2 more checkboxes would show up Beer, Coffee etc.

Comment: @colin: use the second `echo` snippet then, if the `$checked` variable is empty, the checkbox isn't checked, and you can hide the div.

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question, now I have to find out how to put a product's "products" in the div

Comment: @colin: Way ahead of you... Added a basic ajax setup to do just that (determine what checkbox is checked, send that data to the server so it can send back the sub-products to go with it)

Comment: I haven't tried your method yet, but im wondering if this would work?
If not, I will give yours a try altough im not really experienced with it 

The code is at the bottom of the original post, 

the idea is to select the corresponding items of each products and make a hidden div that only shows when checked (like the original one you made)
PS: the code is a mess but maybe it contains some thing that may work